# substitute for tuna in Poke

Tags: substitutions, tuna

I like Poke, but prefer to avoid tuna (due to sustainability concerns).

I tried with salmon and it was a mixed result. The taste was good, but too many bones and hard stuff, at least in the particular piece I got. Is there a way to avoid that with salmon, maybe a particular cut?

Otherwise, what would be a good meaty fish alternative? Halibut, perhaps?

Comment: Any sushi grade fish would be good, pick the one you like.

Comment: I might ask a separate question about salmon (right cut and/or removing bones). For the substitution question I'm a bit torn - I kind of agree with Max, most anything will work, but perhaps people could try to help you stay closer to tuna. But if you want to aim for that... is it only tuna that you want to avoid? Or are you avoiding it for a reason that might apply to other fish too?

Comment: @Max: that's not a comment; that's an answer...  If you answer and ping me, I'll come back and upvote...  **:-)**

Comment: Look into Ora king salmon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short answer: octopus, salmon, shellfish

[long answer:](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=26&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi5iYm-1_3YAhUrzIMKHaoeAXIQmhMI3wEwGQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FPoke_(fish_salad)&usg=AOvVaw0gGqtcbYbxRSmhVh-ud4Ic)

Traditional forms are aku (an oily tuna) and he'e (octopus)... (aka)"Tako" Poke...

ahi poke is generally made with yellowfin tuna... raw salmon or various shellfish as a main ingredient...

Answer (score 0):

How about imitation crab meat? Not gourmet but I think it taste nice.